# How to convert from `float` to boost::python::extract<float>

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am trying to write a makefile and produce a `.so` file to use a `C++` function in `Python` code. The `C++` function returns a `float` value, I do not know how should I write it using `boost::python`. Here is what I have:

```
    #include "sift_tracker.hpp"
    sift_tracker g_tracker;
    boost::python::extract<float> get_score() {
          return g_tracker.get_score();
    }
```

`get_score()` is a function written in `C++` that returns a `float` value. When I run this code, I am getting this error:
`could not convert from ‘float’ to ‘boost::python::extract<float>`

I know that floating numbers in `python` are `64 bits` and in `C++`, they are `32 bits`. But I am not sure if this the reason for getting this error. Any suggestion?

Comment: [`boost::python::extract<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/to_from_python_type_conversion.html#to_from_python_type_conversion.boost_python_extract_hpp.class_template_extract) is a helper used to extract values from python objects. It doesn't make any sense to return its instance like you do.